# jekyll keeps throwing up errors locally

Tags: jekyll

So ive started working on my jekyll site locally but i cant build or serve it has it keeps throwing up these errors
first it said i had no github api so i asked around and they said install jekyll-github-meta and that lead on to loads of other errors. but the trouble is i keep having to remove important parts like this error

Liquid Exception: Invalid syntax for include tag. File contains invalid characters or sequences: Valid syntax: {% include file.ext param='value' param2='value' %} in /Users/Julie/Documents/GitHub/foamey/_layouts/posts.html

but if i change it from {{ include {{ site.nav }} }} to the local link it will be broken when i upload it
heres the link to the repo if you want to see the files

https://github.com/ire4ever1190/foamey

jekyll build -t

Configuration file: C:/Users/Julie/Documents/GitHub/foamey/_config.yml
            Source: C:/Users/Julie/Documents/GitHub/foamey
       Destination: C:/Users/Julie/Documents/GitHub/foamey/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating...
  Liquid Exception: Invalid syntax for include tag. File contains invalid characters or sequences: Valid syntax: {% include file.ext param='value' param2='value' %} in /Users/Julie/Documents/GitHub/foamey/_layouts/posts.html
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.2.1/lib/jekyll/tags/include.rb:63:in `validate_file_name': Invalid syntax for include tag. File contains invalid characters or sequences: (ArgumentError)

Valid syntax:

{% include file.ext param='value' param2='value' %}

```
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.2.1/lib/jekyll/tags/include.rb:127:in `render'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/liquid-3.0.6/lib/liquid/block.rb:151:in `render_token'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/liquid-3.0.6/lib/liquid/profiler/hooks.rb:5:in `block in render_token_with_profiling'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/liquid-3.0.6/lib/liquid/profiler.rb:80:in `profile_token_render'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/liquid-3.0.6/lib/liquid/profiler/hooks.rb:4:in `render_token_with_profiling'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/liquid-3.0.6/lib/liquid/block.rb:135:in `block in render_all'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/liquid-3.0.6/lib/liquid/block.rb:122:in `each'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/liquid-3.0.6/lib/liquid/block.rb:122:in `render_all'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/liquid-3.0.6/lib/liquid/block.rb:108:in `render'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/liquid-3.0.6/lib/liquid/template.rb:210:in `block in render'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/liquid-3.0.6/lib/liquid/template.rb:262:in `with_profiling'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/liquid-3.0.6/lib/liquid/template.rb:209:in `render'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/liquid-3.0.6/lib/liquid/template.rb:222:in `render!'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.2.1/lib/jekyll/liquid_renderer/file.rb:28:in `block (2 levels) in render!'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.2.1/lib/jekyll/liquid_renderer/file.rb:40:in `measure_bytes'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.2.1/lib/jekyll/liquid_renderer/file.rb:27:in `block in render!'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.2.1/lib/jekyll/liquid_renderer/file.rb:47:in `measure_time'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.2.1/lib/jekyll/liquid_renderer/file.rb:26:in `render!'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.2.1/lib/jekyll/renderer.rb:114:in `render_liquid'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.2.1/lib/jekyll/renderer.rb:157:in `place_in_layouts'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.2.1/lib/jekyll/renderer.rb:71:in `run'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.2.1/lib/jekyll/site.rb:447:in `block (2 levels) in render_docs'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.2.1/lib/jekyll/site.rb:445:in `each'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.2.1/lib/jekyll/site.rb:445:in `block in render_docs'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.2.1/lib/jekyll/site.rb:444:in `each'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.2.1/lib/jekyll/site.rb:444:in `render_docs'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.2.1/lib/jekyll/site.rb:190:in `render'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.2.1/lib/jekyll/site.rb:69:in `process'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.2.1/lib/jekyll/command.rb:26:in `process_site'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.2.1/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:63:in `build'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.2.1/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:34:in `process'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.2.1/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:16:in `block (2 levels) in init_with_program'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `call'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `block in execute'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `each'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `execute'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/program.rb:42:in `go'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary.rb:19:in `program'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.2.1/exe/jekyll:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: could you please run jekyll build -t to get some more information here?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the update. I just tried to build the project and it works fine for me.

I noticed that you are usign Jeykll 3.2.1 and not the current version used by Github Page (3.3.1): https://pages.github.com/versions/

Try to run `gem update jekyll` and see, if this helps.